# Adding a new developer to git repo who might not know what they are doing

Tags: git, github

I work in the physical sciences, and me and one of my group members have a private git repo that we've been developing on for the past 1.5 years. Recently, a new member joined our group who will be working on a project which is tangential to our code development, and for which he will need to use the code and likely modify it to some extent. Having said this, from my initial interactions with him it seems that he might not know what he's doing and it's difficult to have productive discussions with him about why this is the case (not sure if this is because of language barriers or something more fundamental). While I hope for the best, I'm also wanting to prepare for the worst (what I'm worrying about is him messing up the code, potentially the git repo organization itself, etc.). Obviously git has version control, and so we can always go back to previous checkpoints if we want the code from before he started working on it.

But I'm wondering, is there a better thing to do in this situation? I don't use many of the git features (don't even use different branches), and so am wondering what might be the best way to share the codebase with him while protecting our own work in the case that things go awry (and also easily allow us to adopt and continue with his contributions if things end up working out well with him after all)? Should he just start working on it, and if we don't like it, we can always branch off from a previous version?

Comment: Have him work on a branch so that you can more easily see what he is doing, then merge things back in when you're comfortable with what he has done.

Comment: Or just have him fork his own copy of the repository and send over pull requests for any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could have the new member fork the private repo (he doesn't even have to have a paid account for that) and have him submit his changes as pull requests. This way you have full control over your code and have a mechanism for reviewing his part before accepting it.